# How do I check if Gtk.CheckButton is checked?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I am using GTK and I have inserted a `CheckButton` (GTK version of checkbox) to a window. Now I need to get if it's checked or not. How do I do that?

Comment: does it have a `Checked` property?

Comment: here is a `GTKSharp` link http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp:_Buttons `Google is your friend` [Beginners Guide GTK](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpBeginnersGuide)

Comment: Be sure I was googling was this, and if I easily found an answer, I wouldn't ask here. If it's so clear to you, why you just didn't answer instead of telling me to use google?

Comment: Personally I don't see any problem with this question. I voted it up because I remember having this exact question at one point.  The property name is, well, odd, and doesn't jump out as the way to determine the checked state.

Comment: I think that reason so many people voted down is that I didn't write it well, from title some people probably thought I am asking about checkbox, so they voted it down without actually even reading what I am asking for...

Comment: I'm also up-voting this, because coming from a Windows background, I intuitively expected there to be a Checked property, even though the name might be different. Having the answer posted below means I can move beyond this obstacle in 5 seconds as opposed to reading a tutorial for 1 minute, which 
is a meaningful time savings, considering this won't be the only such question that I will need to address.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Despite I fail to see advantage of QA site which answers with: google is your friend, I will answer this question for people who are (googling) looking for the same...

The property `Active` of `Gtk.CheckButton` is alternative of `Checked` in checkbox

so

```
if (checkbox.Active)
{
     // the checkbox was checked
} else
{
    // it wasn't checked
}
```

Comment: I didn't found that inside the Mono Guide. I really didn't found anything inside that guide, even a snippet or sample about functions mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

First answer on google for the items `gtk checkbox sharp` (at least for me) yields http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp:_Buttons, goto the section `Toggle buttons` & `Check buttons`.

It's the `Active` member you need to check